# Search Domain With A List Of Names To Determine If Account Exists

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I currently have a text file with a list of domain user accounts. I want to take that list and run it against the domain to see if the account actually exists or not. Then eventually I want to delete the folders that do not have domain accounts.

But right now I am stuck at checking the list against the domain to see if there is an account or not. Here is what I have:

```
Get-Content -Path $domainProfilesList |
    ForEach-Object {
         Try{
              Get-ADUser $_
         }catch{
              Write-Host $_" not found"
              Continue
         }
}
```

$domainProfilesList is the varible that contains the path to the text document with all the profile names in it.

When this script is ran, it stops on the first error: 
*"Cannot find an object with identity: "userName" under: 'DC=my,DC=lab'. not found"*

Comment: i don't think `continue` works as you expect when in a `ForEach-Object` block. i _think_ it simply exits the pipeline.

Comment: Can you show us the first couple of lines of your text file? The error suggests that it is actually a CSV file with a header `userName`..

Answer (score 0):

when you use `continue` in a `ForEach-Object` call ... it *exits* the loop instead of continuing to the next item. why? *because there is no next item* ... the pipeline gave ONE item to the F-O call and there is no actual *loop*. [*grin*]

lookee ...

```
1..10 |
    ForEach-Object {
        if ($_ % 3 -eq 0)
            {
            '{0} is evenly divisible by 3' -f $_
            }
            else
            {
            '{0} is not evenly divisible by 3.' -f $_

            #continue
            }
        }
```

output with the `continue` commented out ...

```
1 is not evenly divisible by 3.
2 is not evenly divisible by 3.
3 is evenly divisible by 3
4 is not evenly divisible by 3.
5 is not evenly divisible by 3.
6 is evenly divisible by 3
7 is not evenly divisible by 3.
8 is not evenly divisible by 3.
9 is evenly divisible by 3
10 is not evenly divisible by 3.
```

output with `continue` enabled ...

```
1 is not evenly divisible by 3.
```